# Make TableRows even width

Tags: java, android, width, tablelayout, tablerow

Below is what my screen looks like:

[image]

You can see that in row 1, the two buttons are not aligned evenly since the right box is 2 lines and the left box is 1 line.  Also, you can see in row 3 that the buttons are wider since they are both 3 lines each.

Is there a way to make the rows the same height?  Sort of like how in a `LinearLayout` you can use `android:layout_width="#"`.  I have posted all the code in my XML since it is relatively short.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="65dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subHeader"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/scrollviewborder"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/jc" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/tencommandments"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exodus" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/genesis" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/holydays" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />      

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/facts" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/random" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `match_parent` in your button with the id `jc`.

Comment: This at least made the two buttons on row 1 the same height.  But all 4 rows are not the same height still.  I have updated my opening post with the new code and a new screenshot.

Comment: @Matt because your text is different for each button inevitably the height of the buttons is going to end up different on some devices because there will be less space horizontally to put the text. The only real option you have if you want them to be the exact same height on every device is to hardcode height to some dp value.

Comment: So there is no way to see that row 3 is going to have the tallest height, and then match rows 1, 2 and 4 as the height as row 3?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your layout, redone.  You're going to want to add the lines referring to your drawables in -- I took them out since I didn't have access to them.  Pay attention to how the values for weight are fractional, and think of the amount of space available to a widget within a container in terms of a percentage of that space.  This paradigm shift should elevate your understanding of the weight attribute.

Also, try to avoid using `fill_parent`, which has been deprecated in favor of `match_parent` in API 8 and above unless your really want to support old, moldy versions of Android (less than 1% of the installed base).

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="65dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subHeader"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/jc" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/tencommandments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exodus" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/genesis" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/holydays" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />      

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/facts" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/random" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```